# Does Task.Run generate overhead with I/O bound operation?

Tags: c#, async-await

I would like to download data in asynchronous way
from various services via `HttpClient` (for test purposes I created few methods with `Task.Delay`). So first I decided to create list of tasks and after all use 
`await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` to wait for everything.

Everything is working as I want but there is one problem if I pass lambda to
 `tasks.Add()`. I have to use `Task.Run` because without it can't use await inside.

So my question is:

Will this `Task.Run()` generate additional overhead? Because with I/O bound operation we shouldn't use `Task.Run` but simple async await.

```
class Program
{
    public static async Task<int> DownloadDelay15()
    { await Task.Delay(15000); return 15; }

    public static async Task<int> DownloadDelay2()
    { await Task.Delay(1000); return 2; }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
        tasks.Add(DownloadDelay15());
        tasks.Add(DownloadDelay2());
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => //additional overhead?
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return 6;
        }));

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedSeconds = watch.Elapsed.Seconds;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Task.Run creates and starts one task, just like your other tasks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> if I pass lambda to tasks.Add(). I have to use Task.Run because without it can't use await inside.

You cannot pass a lambda to `Add`; you need to pass a `Task` to `Add`. You can do this by creating another method:

```
async Task<int> DownloadDelay6()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  return 6;
}

var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
tasks.Add(DownloadDelay15());
tasks.Add(DownloadDelay2());
tasks.Add(DownloadDelay6());
```

> Does this Task.Run() will generate additonal overhead? Because with IO bound operation we shouldn't use Task.Run but simple async await.

Yes; `Task.Run` runs its delegate on a thread pool thread, so there is some additional overhead. It is not a lot, but it is there.

Comment: And it might not run right away if the thread pool needs to grow to schedule that task.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to pass a lambda to your list, I suggest you make it a list of delegates, not a list of tasks. You can then convert it to a list of tasks so you can await it.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var jobs = new List<Func<Task<int>>>
    {
        DownloadDelay15,
        DownloadDelay2,
        async () => { await Task.Delay(1000); return 6; }
    };

    var tasks = jobs.Select(job => job()).ToList();

    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedSeconds = watch.Elapsed.Seconds;
}
```

To answer your question, yes, `Task.Run` creates some overhead, as tasks that are executed in this fashion are put on the thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Task.Run`...

1. There will be additional overhead.
2. Your program will probably run faster.

This may sound contradictory. The reason that your program will run faster, assuming that you'll run it on a multi-core machine, is because the tasks will be started in parallel. This may be irrelevant if your tasks are startable with zero CPU demands, and the tasks in your example are just like that, but not all tasks can be started instantly. Some tasks include synchronous code that runs before the task is started. Without `Task.Run` this synchronous code will run sequentially, since one task will be started after another. With `Task.Run` the synchronous code will run in parallel in all available cores. The additional overhead of `Task.Run` will be payed by the system as a whole, and not by your program alone. The overhead is minuscule, around 2 microseconds of CPU time per invocation, so most probably you won't notice any difference eitherway, unless you have several hundreds of thousands tasks to run at once.